# uploading file from android app into desired folder

Tags: php, mysql

I wan to upload file from android app using PHP in specific folder below is the code which I have tried. 
pleas help me what is wrong in this code and please suggest me some easy solution for this or is this method right to upload files from android app on serever

```
 $response = array();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        //checking the required parameters from the request
        if(isset($_POST['exp']) && isset($_POST['employee_id']) && isset($_FILES['pdf']['name'])  ){

                //connecting to the database
            $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die('Unable to Connect...');

            $resume_name = $_POST['exp'];
            $employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];
            $file_data = $_FILES['pdf']['name'];

            $upload_path = 'Images/Employee_Profile_Picture/'.$employee_id.'/Resume/';

              //getting file info from the request
            $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['pdf']['name']);

             //getting the file extension
            $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

            //file url to store in the database
            $file_url = $upload_path . getFileName($employee_id). '.'. $extension;

            //file path to upload in the server
            $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName($employee_id);

         try{

            if(file_exists($upload_path))
            {
               $existing_file = glob($upload_path."/*.*");
               $empty_file = implode(" ",$existing_file);

              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['name'],$upload_path) ;

    $sql = "UPDATE employee_registration SET resume_name ='$resume_name', resume_path='$file_url' where employee_id ='$employee_id'";

               //adding the path and name to database
               if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                    //filling response array with values

                    $response['Success'] = "File Uploaded Successfully...!";
                    echo json_encode($response);

                }
                else
                {
                  $response['Error'] = "File Uploading Error...!";
                  echo json_encode($response);
                }

            }
                else
                {
                      mkdir('Images/Employee_Profile_Picture/'.$employee_id.'/Resume');
                      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['name'],$upload_path) ;

        $sql = "UPDATE employee_registration SET resume_name ='$resume_name', resume_path='$file_url' where employee_id ='$employee_id'";

                            //adding the path and name to database
                            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
                            {

                             //filling response array with values

                                 $response['Success'] = "File Uploaded Successfully...!";
                                 echo json_encode($response);

                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $response['Error'] = "File Uploading Error...!";
                                echo json_encode($response);
                            }

                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                $response['error']=true;
                $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
            }
    }

    }


      //here is my method getFileName

function getFileName($employee_id)
 {

   //mysql query to fetch data 
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT resume_path from employee_registration where 
     employee_id = '$employee_id'") or die(mysql_error());
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
   {
     $response=$row['resume_path'];
   }
    $resume_name = explode("/", $response);
   echo $resume_name[4]; 
   return $resume_name;
  }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Edit your question and add some description for describing your problem .[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , [verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise you get downvoted your question

Answer (score 2):

Change below line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['name'],$upload_path) ;
```

To

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],$upload_path) ;
```

tmp_name should be used to upload the file, as it has the full path of the file where it is temporarily stored. Where as the name contain only the name of file without any path information.

Answer (score 0):

if this doenst work `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],$upload_path) ;`

kindly use this file_put_contents($upload_path,$_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name']);